I'm getting C2976 'std::array': too few template arguments & C3699 '^': cannot use this indirection on type 'std::array' in this code
I am still a beginner and have no idea what's going on here.
My code:
#include "MainForm.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include "songs.h"
#include "SongsInPlaylist.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

void main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    songs_DLList l;
    songs_buildFromFile(l);
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    DSAProjectOnceMore::MainForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
    
    songs_menu(l, "songs/test.wav");
}

The error:
C2976 'std::array': too few template arguments & C3699 '^': cannot use this indirection on type 'std::array'

the error is in the void main(...) line.
I could've sworn the code was giving no errors here until I added the source files and header files.

You've falling for the using namespace trap, remove : using namespace System;Also check the other header files for using namespace std; and remove them.

@PepijnKramer I don't think C++/CLI array comes from namespace System, so it will not help to remove it in this case (despite being a good practice). As I wrote in my answer I believe the issue is using namespace std;.

@wohlstad Yup, casing matters. System::Array is a thing. Now the key thing is where did the "using namespace std;" come from ;)

Your error message:

'std::array': too few template arguments & C3699 '^': cannot use this
indirection on type 'std::array' in this code

Is referring to std::array, which is a C++ standard library class.
Whereas in this line:
void main(array<String^>^ args)

array is supposed to be a C++/CLI .NET array.
The probable cause for this error is that in any of the #included headers you have both:
#include <array>     // for using the C++ std::array

And:
using namespace std; // to avoid the need to use the std:: prefix

This causes the compiler to assume mistakenly that array<String^>^ args is referring to the C++ std::array.
It's a good example of What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.
The solution is to remove using namespace std; from your source code (particularly from all your headers). This will likely to cause some compilation errors, which you will solve by adding the std:: prefix where needed.

In addition, use entry point  [STAThread]int main(array<String^>^ args)
And add using namespace Project1;//change this
replace Project1 with the namespace in MainForm.h.
#include "MainForm.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include "songs.h"
#include "SongsInPlaylist.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace Project1;//change this
[STAThread]
int main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    songs_DLList l;
    songs_buildFromFile(l);
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    DSAProjectOnceMore::MainForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
    
    songs_menu(l, "songs/test.wav");
    return 0
}

